# Compute $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$.

No idea in my mind. Any help?

#### Context

I want to calculate the expected value of bits per symbols in adaptive arithmetic coding when the number of symbols goes to infinity.

Comment: there exists a formula but this formual contains not elementary functions.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner so it does not simplify in a compact form?

Comment: How about calculating the numerical value of the sum for $n=2,3,4,5$, say, to do at least _some_ work on your question? Or at least telling us _why_ this sum is of interest to you?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I want to calculate the expected value of bits per symbols in adaptive arithmetic coding when the number of symbols goes to infinity. Be sure that this is not an exam or homework question

Comment: See [A$046825$](http://oeis.org/A046825) and [A$046826$](http://oeis.org/A046826).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{1}{n\choose k}=\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{(n-k)!k!}{n!}=\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{\Gamma(n-k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}=\sum^{n}_{k=0}(n+1)B(n-k+1,k+1)$$
The last summation is in terms of Euler's Beta function. Beta function has the following integral represantion:
$$B(x,y)=\int^{1}_{0}u^{x-1}(1-u)^{y-1}\,du$$
for $\Re(x),\Re(y)>0$. Hence we could rewrite the last summation as follows
\begin{align}\sum^{n}_{k=0}(n+1)B(n-k+1,k+1)&=(n+1)\sum^{n}_{k=0}B(n-k+1,k+1)\\&=(n+1)\sum^{n}_{k=0}\int^{1}_{0}u^{n-k}(1-u)^{k}\,du\\&
=(n+1)\int^{1}_{0}\{\sum^{n}_{k=0}u^{n-k}(1-u)^{k})\},du\\&
=(n+1)\int^{1}_{0}u^n\{\sum^{n}_{k=0}(\frac{1}{u}-1)^{k})\}\,du\\
&=(n+1)\int^{1}_{0}u^n\frac{(\frac{1}{u}-1)^{n+1}-1}{\frac{1}{u}-2}\,du\\
&=(n+1)\int^{1}_{0}\frac{(1-u)^{n+1}-u^{n+1}}{1-2u}\,du\\
&=-\frac{2(n+1)}{n+2}\cdot_2F_1(1,n+2,n+3,2)\end{align}
where the last expression is the value of the integral in terms of hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice!

I have the same idea the final result is:
$$F(1,1,-n,0)=\left(\frac{G(-n)G(-n-2)}{G(-n-1)^2}\right)=\left(\frac{\pi}{-\sin(n+1)\pi}\right)n!\left(\frac{\pi}{(-\sin(n+3)\pi}\right)\\(n+1)!\left(\frac{\pi}{(-\sin(n+2)\pi}\right)(n+1)!\left(\frac{-2(n+1)}{(n+2)}\right)$$

(There is a line break between the two parts of the equation, for those wondering)

Comment: Here is a guide on how to use mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference